# How to account for conversation IDs being the same when retrieving Outlook Messages in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

By default, the Graph API for

```
/me/mailFolders/{folderId}/messages
```

Will return 10 messages.  I want to group together the messages much like the Outlook Web UI does.  So if 3 messages are from the same conversation, to the user it'll look like only 7 messages came back.  Is there a way to account for this through API?  Or should I just bump up the number of messages to make it difficult to really see how many messages came back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph considers each message as a distinct object (which after all technically they are).

From a user experience perspective, I would consider switching to "at least 10". If you pull page 1 and get 7 unique conversations, pull page 2 immediately and consider that a single operation. If you're pulling 10 per page, at most the user would see 19 messages returned from a single pull.

Comment: Yea, that was a dumb question on my part.  I've basically implemented what you've described.